# What is a realistic example for the use of mapc?

Tags: mapping, common-lisp

I was just thinking about the different mapping functions in `common-lisp` as described in the [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm). I am pretty much used to `mapcar` and think it is the easiest to understand. But what is a real world example of using `mapc`? The example in the `hyperspec` uses it for a side-effect as far as I get it. But why does it return the list argument?

Is there a general rule when such a mapping is favourable over an iteration using `loop` etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## What is a real world example of using `mapc`?

`(mapc #'print my-list)` is clearer than `(dolist (x my-list) (print x))`

## Why does it return the list argument?

The functional heritage imposes the thinking that every function should return something useful; for [`mapc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) it is the original list.

I think [`mapc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) returns its list argument for the same reason [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) does - to simplify debugging by sprinkling your code with output. E.g., suppose you do something like

```
(mapcar #'important-processing
        list-with-weird-elements)
```

You want to see what's inside the list while preserving the logic:

```
(mapcar #'important-processing
        (mapc #'show-weird-object list-with-weird-elements))
```

Also, a lot of things in CL are for ["hysterical reasons"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html).

## Is there a general rule when such a mapping is favourable over an iteration using `loop` etc.?

Only if you already have a function which does what you need, like [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) above.

Comment: I really like "hysterical reasons"!

Comment: @MartinBuchmann Also known as "hysterical raisins", if you feel fruity.